# C++ Procedure Entry Point Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, runtime-error

I've been getting an abort dialog in Visual Studio.
[image: this error message]

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DateTime
{
public:
    DateTime(unsigned year, unsigned month, unsigned date, unsigned hour, unsigned minute, unsigned second);
    DateTime(unsigned year, unsigned month, unsigned date);
    ~DateTime();
    std::string get_string();
private:
    unsigned year;
    unsigned month;
    unsigned day;
    unsigned hour;
    unsigned minute;
    unsigned second;
};

std::string DateTime::get_string()
{
    // dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss
    std::string day_s = (this->day < 10) ? "0" + this->day : std::to_string(this->day);
    std::string month_s = (this->month < 10) ? "0" + this->month : std::to_string(this->month);
    std::string year_s = std::to_string(this->year);
    std::string hour_s = (this->hour < 10) ? "0" + this->hour : std::to_string(this->hour);
    std::string minute_s = (this->minute < 10) ? "0" + this->minute : std::to_string(this->minute);
    std::string second_s = (this->second < 10) ? "0" + this->second : std::to_string(this->second);

    return day_s + "/" + month_s + "/" + year_s + " " + hour_s + ":" + minute_s + ":" + second_s;
}

DateTime::DateTime(unsigned year, unsigned month, unsigned date)
{
    if (month > 12 || day > 31)
            throw std::out_of_range("DateTime out of valid range");

    unsigned max_d = 31;

    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        max_d = 30;
    else if (month == 2) {
        max_d = 28;
        if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
            max_d = 29;
    }

    if (day > max_d)
        throw std::out_of_range("DateTime out of valid range");

    this->year = year;
    this->month = month;
    this->day = day;

    this->hour = 0;
    this->minute = 0;
    this->second = 0;

}

DateTime::DateTime(unsigned year, unsigned month, unsigned date, unsigned hour, unsigned minute, unsigned second)
{
    if (month > 12 || day > 31 || hour > 24 || minute > 60 || second > 60)
            throw std::out_of_range("DateTime out of valid range");

    unsigned max_d = 31;

    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        max_d = 30;
    else if (month == 2) {
        max_d = 28;
        if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
            max_d = 29;
    }

    if (day > max_d)
        throw std::out_of_range("DateTime out of valid range");

    this->year = year;
    this->month = month;
    this->day = day;
    this->hour = hour;
    this->minute = minute;
    this->second = second;

}

DateTime::~DateTime()
{
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    DateTime d1(2018, 5, 14);

    std::cout << d1.get_string();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I'm not using precompiled headers because I've been compiling it in the terminal and tried to debug it in Visual Studio. In the terminal the error I was getting is:

> myprog.exe
>   Entry point not found
>   The procedure entry point
>   _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitsIcESalcEE7_M_dataEv could
>   not be located in the dynamic library link C:......\myprog.exe

I'm very far from understanding what this means. Could someone help me?

I believe this is a runtime error? I've searched about similar errors and most of them has something to do with dll. Is this the case?

Edit:
I compiled the source file with `g++ myProg.cpp -o myprog`

Comment: Your constructors accept a `date` argument that you don't use, yet you compare to `day` which is your member variable

Comment: When you hit "Retry" to drop into the debugger, what did you find?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Rather than declaring `~DateTime();` with an empty user defined implementation `DateTime::~DateTime()
{
}`, keep your destructor [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) by either leaving it out entirely or declaring it `~DateTime() = default;` .

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer ! Sharp eyes you have! But I'm still getting the error. @Mark Ransom It triggrered a breakpoint at line ```unsigned max_d = 31;``` of the constructor with 3 arguments. Maybe I have to treat the exception above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string operator+ doesn't have any overloads that accept an `unsigned` right-hand-side.

Replace

```
std::string day_s = (this->day < 10) ? "0" + this->day : std::to_string(this->day);
```

with

```
std::string day_s = (this->day < 10) ? "0" + std::to_string(this->day) : std::to_string(this->day);
```

and so on.